# How to add a style sheet only to child page without affecting to the master page?

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages

I tried to add some special features to child page in my project without applying it to the master page. Therefore i added a style sheet to it and now it gives me several warnings as below.

> Warning   1   Error updating JScript IntelliSense: System\JS\materialize.js: Expected identifier, string or number @ 1774:16  System\agencyAdmin.aspx 1   1    Appeal
>
> Warning   2   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'td'. System\agencyAdmin.aspx   8   6 Appeal
>
> Warning   4   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'data-collapsible' is not a valid attribute of element 'ul'. System\agencyAdmin.aspx 14  33  Competition Appeal

Also when i execute the program and when loading the relevant page, browser diplsays an error as "Internet Explorer has stopped working".
Then it displays following error.

> JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I have tried answers in this site and some other found on the internet. But didn't work for me.
Here is the code in master page header section

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CDDS_Master.master.cs" Inherits="ccs.CDDS_Master"  %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">

    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
      <title></title>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="agency" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    
 <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            height: 75; 
            width: 1024px;
            border-collapse: collapse; 
           
        }
        .styPageData
        {
          height:625px;
            width:934px;
      
            vertical-align:top;
        }
        .style4
        {
            height: 113px;
            width: 100%;
 
        }
        .style5
        {
            width: 925px;
            height: 103px;
        }
        .style7
        {
            width: 653px;
            height: 78px;
        }
        .style8
        {
            height: 78px;
            width: 245px;
        }
       
        .style9
        {
            width: 183px;
        }
        .styTreeWith
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .reportView
        {
            overflow:scroll;
        }
       
    </style>
    <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
</head>
```

Here is the code in child page

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ccs.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="agencyAdmin.aspx.cs" Inherits="ccs.agencyAdmin" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="agency" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <link href="CSS/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="JS/materialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="divCol" style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left">
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header">
                    <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header">
                    <i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header">
                    <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: come on, think and work a little bit before come here and ask some one else to work for you - its not that hard to solve it.

Comment: To me yes. I've tried lots of things in the internet. There are lots of answers and i tried them too

Comment: Just place in the correct order the ContentPlace and add some more if you need to. Now if you do not understand what all that is...

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code in child class



 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ccs.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
            CodeBehind="agencyAdmin.aspx.cs" Inherits="ccs.agencyAdmin" %>


        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <link href="CSS/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="CSS/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <script src="JS/materialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JS/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            height: 75; 
            width: 1024px;
            border-collapse: collapse; 

        }
        .styPageData
        {
             height:625px;
            width:934px;

            vertical-align:top;
        }
        .style4
        {
            height: 113px;
            width: 100%;

        }
        .style5
        {
            width: 925px;
            height: 103px;
        }
        .style7
        {
            width: 653px;
            height: 78px;
        }
        .style8
        {
            height: 78px;
            width: 245px;
        }

        .style9
        {
            width: 183px;
        }
        .styTreeWith
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .reportView
        {
            overflow:scroll;
        }

    </style>
        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="agency" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


            <div id="divCol" style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left">
                <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </asp:Content>
```

Comment: use edited code some time internal css not working from master page.